# Cursor Returning null After DB Overwritten

Tags: android, android-listview, listadapter, android-sqlite, android-cursor

My app has a static DB which I need to update with new content. The schema won't change. I've put the DB into `assets/` and when the app launches it, it copies the DB (in the `SQLiteOpenHelper` constructor) into the application's `databases/` directory. The copy code is as follows:

```
private void importAssets(boolean overWrite) throws IOException
{
    AssetManager am = mCtx.getAssets();
    InputStream in = am.open(DB_NAME);
    FileOutputStream out;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int len;
    File dir, db;

    dir = new File(DB_DIR);
    dir.mkdirs();
    db = new File(dir, DB_NAME);

    // if not first run return
    if (!overWrite && db.exists())
    {
        Log.i(TAG, DB_DIR + "/" + DB_NAME + " exists, do nothing");
        in.close();
        return;
    }

    // copy the DB from assets to standard DB dir created above
    out = new FileOutputStream(db);
    while ((len = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
    {
        out.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }

    out.flush();
    out.close();
    in.close();

    if (!db.exists())
    {
        Log.e(TAG, DB_DIR + "/" + DB_NAME + " does not exist");
    }

}
```

The variable `overWrite` is flag that tells `importAssets()` whether or not to overwrite an existing DB. This is only set to `true` if the appropriate conditions are matched in `SQLiteOpenHelper.onUpgrade()`. In that case, the `FileOutputStream` truncates the existing file and overwrites it with the new one from `assets/`.

The reason I'm doing this is that I have a lot of records that I'd rather not hard-code into the Java source. I just want to drop the DB in there for the user to access. The user cannot modify the DB, it's for viewing only.

The main activity is a subclass of `ListActivity`. It reads the data out of the DB and displays it in a list using a `Cursor` and a `ListArray`. This is done in `onResume()` as follows:

```
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();

    mContent = new PocketbookContent(this);
    mDB = mContent.getReadableDatabase();

    mRows = mDB.query("book_content",
        new String[] { "id", "title" },
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "id", 
        null);

    String[] chapters = new String[mRows.getCount()];
    mRows.moveToFirst();
    for (int i = 0; i < mRows.getCount(); i++)
    {
        // assume title is in column 1
        chapters[i] = mRows.getString(1);
        mRows.moveToNext();
    }

    // set the adapter & insert data into view
    mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        R.layout.toc_row, chapters);
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

`mRows`, `mDB` and `mContent` are all closed in `onPause()`.

When the app is freshly installed, there is no problem. Everything runs fine. The DB is copied from `assets/` into the `databases/` directory and the app runs. The problem occurs on upgrade. When it gets to the point of loading the data from the table into the `Cursor`, the first column of the first row turns out to be `null` and the app crashes with a `NullPointerException`.

Through debugging I have confirmed that what's coming out of the `Cursor` in the first row is `null`, while all other rows are fine. I have also confirmed that the database is intact and all the data is there. I did this by adding code to `importAssets()` to make another copy of the DB from the `databases/` directory (not directly from `assets/`) to the SD card where I can inspect it. What I've concluded is that the `null` row is getting passed to the `ArrayAdapter` constructor and it then crashes. Here's the top part of the stack trace:

```
D/AndroidRuntime( 6058): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm( 6058): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6058): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 6058): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime( 6058):        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:355)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6058):        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:323)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6058):        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1430)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6058):        at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1745)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6058):        at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:670)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6058):        at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:727)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6058):        at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1598)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6058):        at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1260)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6058):        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
```

Why is the first row in my `Cursor null`? I don't think there's a problem with the DB copy/overwrite, as it works fine on a fresh install, and the DB that's copied on upgrade is intact on inspection using `sqlite3`.

The target API level is `10`.

**Edit**: Here is `toc_row.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:padding="3px"
    android:textSize="27dp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />
```

**Edit**: When I put debug prints in the `while()` loop, it shows that the data coming out of the `Cursor` is `null`, but for the first row only:

```
V/RenderScript_jni(  195): surfaceDestroyed
I/TableOfContents( 6058): NUMROWS: 5
I/TableOfContents( 6058): 0: null
I/TableOfContents( 6058): 1: Introduction
I/TableOfContents( 6058): 2: The Police and Arrest
I/TableOfContents( 6058): 3: Being Detained
I/TableOfContents( 6058): 4: When You are Arrested
D/AndroidRuntime( 6058): Shutting down VM
```

Note, `TableOfContents` is the main activity, subclassed from `ListActivity`.

**Edit**: The `onUpgrade()` method. It calls `importAsssets()` with `overWrite` set to `true`.

```
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVer, int newVer)
{  
    if (ORIG_REL_SCHEMA_VER == oldVer &&
        DB_SCHEMA_VER == newVer)
    {  
        try
        {  
            importAssets(true);
        }
        catch (IOException ioe)
        {  
            Log.e(TAG, "importAssets() exception" + ioe.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit (a kludge discovered)**: I've discovered a workaround that prevents the crash and allows a DB upgrade. It doesn't actually fix the problem, but at least it's not ugly to the user. I modified `importAssets()` by adding a `File.delete()` call:

```
if (!overWrite && db.exists())
{
    Log.i(TAG, DB_DIR + "/" + DB_NAME + " exists, do nothing");
    in.close();
    return;
}
else if (overWrite)
{
    db.delete();
}
```

Since `overWrite` is only true when `importAssets()` is called from `onUpgrade()` this will only happen once. It removes the existing DB and copies the new one from `assets/`. Based on my testing, `File.delete()` doesn't actually take effect until the object is destroyed, so the events are not actually happening as suggested by the code. The first time `TableOfContents.onResume()` is called, the `ArrayAdapter` will show the old data, but on the next call, it will show the new data.

Anyway, that's my kludge, because there seems to be not explanation why `Cursor` gets a `null` value for row 1 when in fact there is data there.

Comment: "The problem occurs on upgrade." Please post your `onUpgrade()` method.

Comment: So... the database packaged in `/assets` does _not_ have any `null` values in the first row, but if `onUpgrade()` is called the `null` values appear in the first row and the existing rows are still there but pushed up one index?

Comment: The DB in `assets/` has no `null` values, that's correct. Whether or not `onUpgrade()` is called, the DB itself has no `null` values. It's just that when the `Cursor` tries to read from the DB (after `onUpgrade()` is called) it obtains a `null` value (from where?) for the first row. All remaining rows in the `Cursor` are as they should be and where they should be.

Comment: The Cursor doesn't return any row that doesn't already exist. If it exists in the Cursor, it exists in the database... You can delete this row, using `WHERE title IS NULL`. You could also change your query or use a CursorAdapter to skip any `null` values.

Comment: The row showing `null` in the output above does have data. It's not a phantom row. The value that should show up as "Import Notice..." So I can't just throw it away. Though I may investigate that to see if I find out anything useful.

Comment: If you want to keep this row but don't want it to crash your app simply change your query to what I posted below.

Answer (score 0):

> The row showing null in the output above does have data. It's not a phantom row. The value that should show up as "Import Notice..."

Then the easiest solution is to skip rows with `null` titles:

```
mRows = mDB.query("book_content",
    new String[] { "id", "title" },
    "WHERE title IS NOT NULL",
    null,
    null,
    null,
    "id", 
    null);
```

This way it won't crash your app and you can keep the notice.

Comment: When I do that, it doesn't crash, but the first row from the DB is missing. Which of course makes sense, because the `Cursor`, for whatever reason, is unable to read the first row.